# MAX() in UPDATE query with field does not work

Tags: mysql, unsigned

I try to update multiple rows at the same time but `amount` can have different starting values.
I want to subtract x amount from `amount` without going below 0. I used `UNSIGNED` for the `amount` field in order to protect the number never to fall below 0.

The following query refuses to update all rows that fall below 0 because of the `UNSIGNED` state:

```sql
UPDATE `table`
   SET `amount` = `amount` - 35
 WHERE `id`
    IN (26984, 131881, 985550, 985569, 985586, 1086766, 1189724)
```

In case `amount` is for example 12, if you subtract 35, it falls below 0 and refuses to update. But I need it to update to 0.

Then I tried to think of `MAX()` to help me not fall below 0, but this does not work:

```
UPDATE `table`
   SET `amount` = MAX(`amount` - 35, 0)
 WHERE `id`
    IN (26984, 131881, 985550, 985569, 985586, 1086766, 1189724)
```

Any idea how to make this work and to make sure the value never falls below 0?

Comment: The function you want is `GREATEST()`. `MAX()` is an aggregation function that calculates the maximum of a value across all the selected rows (in each group if you use `GROUP BY`).

Comment: Thanks, I directly tried it but it gave me the following error: `#1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in 'amount' - 35`

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881122/mysql-bigint-unsigned-value-is-out-of-range/53881228#53881228

Comment: Ok I just discarded `UNSIGNED` and it works now. Thanks a bunch! :D

Comment: The problem is that when the column is UNSIGNED, it doesn't allow the intermediate expression `amount - 35` to be less than 0. @nnichols

Comment: Use `IF(amount < 35, 0, amount-35)`. There's no need to change the datatype.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I was being dumb! Could cast the amount as signed - `SET amount = GREATEST(CAST(amount AS SIGNED) - 35, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, this is how it worked in the end:

```
UPDATE `table`
   SET `amount` = GREATEST(`amount` - 35, 0)
 WHERE `id`
    IN (26984, 131881, 985550, 985569, 985586, 1086766, 1189724)
```

And discarding `UNSIGNED` from `amount`

Comment: If your `amount` column is intended to be `UNSIGNED` so it cannot end up with negative values, don't remove the constraint for the sake of ease on this query.